# Excel/Calc: Combining IF with COUNTIF to produce a value

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested, spreadsheet, countif

*It's late and I'm spent far too long trying, unsuccessfully, to find the solution to what I'm certain should be an easy problem.
I have a value within a cell, derived from another cell. That part of the functions is working fine, the problem is that I now need to add to value.
Currently the second half of the formula looks like this:*

+IF(COUNTIF(R9C20:R12C20,"True")=4,1,IF(AND(COUNTIF(R9C20:R12C20,"True")=2,R12C20="TRUE",1,0)))

*What I'm trying to achieve:*

If there are four values of "True" in the specified range, +1

IF NOT

If there are two values of "True" in the specified range AND the specified cell is "True", +1

IF NOT

+0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following. It looks like you weren't closing out your `AND()` function in the correct location.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(R9C20:R12C20,"TRUE")=4, 1, IF(AND(COUNTIF(R9C20:R12C20,"TRUE")=2, R12C20="TRUE"), 1, 0))
```